# How to prevent IE7 file download popup blocker showing up in ASP.NET App

Tags: .net, download, internet-explorer-7, popup-blocker

> I have an application in .NET that
>   allows user to download document
>   (.rtf) by clicking a downlaod button,
>   then a save/open dialogue opens. It
>   works in IE6, and 8 that ways.
>   However, in IE7, when clicking the
>   button, a popup blocker shows at top
>   of the web page, and user has to click
>   the blocker, and click the dowload
>   file menu to download the file. Once I
>   click the blocker and the download
>   menu within it, the blocker will NOT
>   show up again. However, if I close IE7
>   windows, and start the download
>   process again, the blocker repeat.
>
> How to prevent IE7 file download popup
>   blocker shows up in ASP.NET App on
>   programming side, if possible, as
>   opposed to make settings in IE.
>
> It seems to do with HTTP header, or
>   content type? Ideal solution would be
>   that the blocker never shows up in IE7
>   as in other browser.
>
> It happens even in localhost.
>   Interestingly, the blocker does NOT
>   shows up when clicking HTML archor
>   link to download other files.
>
> The message on the blocker is below:
>
> To help protect your security,
>   Internet Explorer blocked this site
>   from downloading file to your
>   computer. Click here for options.
>   Download File ...

After investigation, what happens is that before sending an url request for a file download, a put operation is sent to server (to save the change before file download), which triggers IE7 security blocker. I would like to know any workaround, and the reason if possible.

Comment: Add site to trusted sites under Security settings.

Comment: @Tomas Voracek, Thanks. That might work. However, Ideally, it should NOT shows up, as in IE6, IE8, firefox and others.

Comment: This is a website in .NET not a client app right?

Comment: @Joshua Thanks. It is a ASP.NET Web Application.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much you can do about what is a documented bug in IE.

Comment: @Joshua In other part of the app, the issue does NOT happen.

Comment: In which comparing the differences in the headers may or may not reveal the cause.

Answer (score 2):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937409, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875817.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The ideal solution would be on programming side if possible. Because it will eliminate the need to setup on client sides.